# Mythbuntu services don't start until after user login

Tags: mysql, services, mythbuntu

I have MythTV front and back end on Mythbuntu running as an 'appliance'.  MythTV isn't terribly stable and the front end will lock up after three or four days of continuously running live TV.  So I have had to show my family how to restart using a single press of the power button to trigger an orderly shutdown.  This works well, but when the system is re-powered and automatically logs in and runs the front end, it always shows the country selection list because MySQL isn't available yet.  It has always done this, but when the TV technician is available (me) it's not a problem.  He can keep backing out of the setup until MySQL is up and then the front end starts.

What I have discovered is that the MySQL service isn't started until after the front end user logs in.  In fact SSH doesn't start either.  If I turn off auto-login, I can't access the box remotely using either `ssh` or the MySQL client. Once the front end user is logged in I can access both.

MySQL takes around 45 seconds to load, which I'm perfectly happy with, but **not** if it doesn't start to load until nearly the moment that `mythtv-frontend` is ready to start too.

I want MySQL (and SSH) to run as global services... not dependent on a user login.  If I can do that I can add a delay (or even a service dependency) to the lightdm configuration.

**Question is: how to I get MySQL (and SSH) to start as during boot?**

- Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Lightdm version is 1.18.3
- Mysql 5.7.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation arises because of a combination of factors:

1. System uses a WiFi connection, not a wired connection.
2. MySQL is bound to an IP address (instead of or as well as localhost)

The default WiFi network setup will only connect to WiFi after you log in.  That means that services like `sshd` and `mysqld` cannot start until after you log in.  If you look at the mysql error log you will see it's repeatedly starting and aborting until you log in.

You can fix this by right-clicking the WiFi symbol in the status bar and choosing `Edit Connections`.  Select your connect and click the `Edit` button.  In the `General` tab check the option that says `All users may connect...`

For command-line junkies, or if you're fixing via `ssh`, you need to [fix the NetworkManager configuration](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/automatic-wifi-connection-on-startup/3216/4):

```
$ sudo su
# cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
# vi connection.name
```

Find the `permissions=` line and delete everything that's after the equal sign.

Restart your machine and your network connection will be established on startup, before any user logs in.  After about 30 seconds `MySQL` will be running.  About 15 seconds later `mythbackend` will running too.